Issues with Calculating Top N Countries and Aggregating Others in Power BI
I'm working on a Power BI report where I need to create a bar chart displaying the top 6 countries by a specific measure and aggregate the remaining countries into an "Others" category. However, I'm encountering some issues with the calculations:
The blue bars (representing the top 6 countries) are not displaying the correct values.
The orange bar (for the "Others" category) shows an incorrect total.
Here is the approach I've taken:

Table Creation
I created a table to include both individual countries and an "Others" category:

TOPeksportCountries = 
UNION(
    VALUES(Trades[Countries]), 
    ROW("Countries", "Others")
)


Measure for Top N Countries
I added a measure to calculate the values for the top N countries:

Top N Countries = 
VAR TopNValue = 6

VAR TopPSubCategory = 
    TOPN(
        TopNValue,
        ALLSELECTED(TOPeksportCountries),
        Trades[AmountEXCLvat]
    )
    
VAR AllSales = 
    CALCULATE(
        Trades[AmountEXCLvat],
        ALLSELECTED(TOPeksportCountries)
    )
VAR OtherSales = 
    AllSales - CALCULATE(
        Trades[AmountEXCLvat], 
        TopPSubCategory
    )

VAR TopNSales = 
    CALCULATE(
        Trades[AmountEXCLvat],
        KEEPFILTERS(
            TopPSubCategory
        )
    )

VAR CurrentPSubCategory = 
    SELECTEDVALUE(TOPeksportCountries[Countries])

RETURN
    IF(
        CurrentPSubCategory = "Others",
        OtherSales,
        TopNSales
    )

The orange bar representing "Others" does not show the expected aggregate value for countries not in the top 6.
How can I correct the calculation for the "Others" category to ensure it displays the proper aggregated value?
Thank you!
Any help or suggestions on how to fix these issues would be greatly appreciated!

Can you provide some data ?

(Alberto Ferrari covers this question on his sqlbi youtube channel.)
